# Why my system is not able to read src file from inet_veins in OMNET++?

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet, sumo

[This is the veins inet error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg43E.png)
Here I first installed omnet++ and then INET Veins now I'm getting the following error while integrating them in VANET:

> make MODE=release all
> cd src && /usr/bin/make
> make[1]: Entering directory '/c/Users/Shriya Bhat/Downloads/VANETProject-master/VANETProject-master/src'
> MSGC: vanetsim/routing/aodvwr/AODVWRControlPackets.msg
> Error: cannot read Bhat/Downloads/veins-5.1/veins-veins-5.1/src
> make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg43E.png): Leaving directory '/c/Users/Shriya Bhat/Downloads/VANETProject-master/VANETProject-master/src'
> make[1]: *** [Makefile:147: vanetsim/routing/aodvwr/AODVWRControlPackets_m.h] Error 1
> make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 2
> "make MODE=release all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
> 21:38:43 Build Failed. 3 errors, 0 warnings. (took 8s.768ms)

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the name of directory of your project containing a space. At compile time, OMNeT++ calls the console commands and space is used as a separator. Therefore the name of project directory mustn't contain a space.

Comment: Thank you sir I will try that.